# Why cannot I determine in code that an object is of a DataTime type?

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire

I have a variable v and when I do

```
print type(v)
```

I do get

```
<type 'DateTime'>
```

but when I do

```
if type(v) in (datetime, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, datetime.time):
```

it is NOT true

The question is: Why ?

EDIT:

The type DateTime is a Spotfire specific type.

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.9.0/TIB_sfire-analyst_7.9.0_api/html/F_Spotfire_Dxp_Data_DataType_DateTime.htm

Comment: How was `v` created? You are showing it's printing type 'DateTime'; if I create a datetime object (eg. datetime.datetime.utcnow()) it shows as `<type 'datetime.datetime'>` and your if condition is True.

Comment: Please put on the `v` definition.

Comment: I will update the question with definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would want to use in this case is [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

```
if isinstance(v, (datetime, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, datetime.time)):
```

On short, the reason is that `type(v)` is more restrictive and can't use subclasses, as that DataTime I imagine it is.

For a detailed overview of `type vs isinstance` head over to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance).

**Also,** note that your type is `<type 'DateTime'>` and not `datetime.datetime`. You need to import that `DateTime` class and used it. Eg:

```
from x.y.z import DateTime

if type(v) in (..., DateTime, ...):
    ....
```

Comment: If nothing works, you can use `type(v).__name__` which will give you the string `'DateTime'`, maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I tested it and this condition was `True`.

```
import datetime


v = datetime.datetime.now()  # maybe your problem is here.
print(type(v))

if type(v) in (datetime, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, datetime.time):
    print("I'm True")

else:
    print("I'm False")
```

Out:

```
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
"I'm True"
```